# Get non matching fields from history table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables.
Employee and EmployeeHistory
EmployeeHistory table is to maintain history of updates done on Employee table.

Here is Employee Table schema

id,name,email,salary

Here is EmployeeHistory table schema

id,name,email,salary,updated_by,updated_ts

I have created trigger to insert new row in EmployeeHistory when new insert or update is happening in Employee table.

Now I am trying to fetch only updated fields from EmployeeHistory table with id as input.

I wrote following query

```
 select * from Employee e
 right join EmployeeHistory eh
 on e.id = eh.id
 and eh.id = 1;
```

This is giving me all fields for eh.id = 1.

I can not know which all fields were updated in advance. Is there any way to get nonmatching fields between Employee and EmployeeHistory table ?

Answer (score 0):

Only output those different records via the below SQL Script.

```sql
SELECT
    E.id,
    EH.NAME,
    E.NAME,
    EH.email,
    E.email,
    EH.salary,
    E.salary,
    EH.updated_by,
    EH.updated_ts 
FROM
    Employee E
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeHistory AS EH ON E.id = EH.id 
    AND (EH.NAME != E.NAME 
    OR EH.email != E.email 
    OR EH.salary != E.salary)
WHERE
    E.id = 1;
```